# How do you make sure that data in a static class is generated, and generated only once?

Tags: c#, static

I have a static class with a static list property on. I want to generate the content of the list only once, and then be able to use it. I of course also want to ensure that the data is actually created so that when an object uses the class it has data in the list. How do I accomplish this?

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static List<int> MyList = new List<int>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyList.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - I want to generate the content of the list only once
> - I also want to ensure that the data is actually created

Your current code ensures exactly that, when you change the constructor to a static one:

```
  static MyClass() { }  // not public or private
```

The class loader will execute the initialization of `MyList` before any other member of the class can be executed. This happens the first time the class is used.

The observable behaviour is that the static members are initalized (once) at the beginning of your application.

Only when you build something where static initializers depend on each other you may have something to think/worry about.

Comment: But each time I reference the class, won't the constructor run all code in it again?

Comment: I believe there is an error in that code. Static classes cannot have instance constructors.

Comment: I missed at first the fact that your ctor is an instance ctor, not allowed in a static class. A static ctor is all you need.

Comment: Ah ok, I will change my constructor to static then. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx) for that, like this:

```
static MyClass()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        MyList.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Note that static constructor does not require nor does it accept any scope modifiers like `public` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an accessor method for your list along with a `bool` variable to track if your list is initialized and filled with data.

Something like:

```
private static List<int> myList;

private static void doInitializeList() {
    myList = new List<int>();
    // fill list here
}

public static List<int> getMyList() {
    if (!_myListInitialized) {
       doInitializeList();
    }
    return myList;
}
```